# SharePoint site home page is not showing the number of views at the bottom of the page

Tags: sharepoint-views

We noticed on our SharePoint sites that the home page is not showing the number of views. We can see the save for later option or like the page.  However, when we go into the site pages library and check any of the other pages, we do see the site views count showing up. Is there something we need to do for having the home page get to display that views count?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Views will not be immediately visible, wait for few hours it'll be reflected.

Quick questions -
Are you using the default page (SitePages/Home.aspx) as the home page or you created a new page and set it as the home page?
Which site template are you using? (Communication or Team)